# how can I access the 2nd <li> tag's text using puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A58E.png)

in the image, the ul tag contains several li tags and I want the text under 2nd li tag only i.e. "254 Beds".

**const numberOfBeds = document.querySelector('.joint-list li').innerText;**

above line of code is giving me only the data inside first li tag but I need only the second one's.

plz help me out with this.

Comment: Please no [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Did you try `nextSibling` or `.joint-list li:last-child`?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks mate, its working !!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, this should work (at least for the first list element):

```
const numberOfBeds = document.querySelectorAll('.joint-list > ul > li')[1].innerText;
```

If you have multiple `<ul>` you may need to rework it with some kind of iteration or another technique, though.

Comment: for first element its working fine but I needed the help with 2nd item, anyways the issue is solved now!! thanks for the suggestion.